# Can you send email from a custom subdomain on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

Is it possible to send email from user@subdomain.example.com ? (example.com being the custom domain name set through Google Apps ) 
  You cannot add that email address to the permissions list because it's an alias so it's automatically assigned to the main account user@example.com so you cannot create an additional account to confirm it and neither to "accept" the invitation because you are identified by google as user@example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot as far as I know, has to be @example.org it being added as an admin to the app. subdomains won't cut it.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible as long as that email address is also added as an admin (owner/developer/viewer) of the app. You can add them through Permissions in the Admin Console.

Comment: that's actually the question. You cannot add that email address as owner/developer/viewer because is actually an alias. For example if you have username@example.com the alias addresses (username@subdomain.example.com) is automatically assigned to "username". Your answer is useless